# ASP.NET and background worker process

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, backgroundworker, signalr

I have a web application running on ASP.NET and using SignalR I support real-time communication between the clients and the server.

I need some type of a worker process that does work in a loop and notifies the clients as needed using the SignalR connections and the web application must be able to call the worker process. (**two-way communication between a worker process and the web application**)

**What would you recommend for communicating between the web application and the worker ?**

A scenario would be:

*The request comes in from the client -> I notify the worker -> the worker does his job -> calls back to the web application -> notifies the client.*

or

*The worker notifies -> web application, uses the SignalR to notify -> clients*

Can I share instances somehow ? Can I run this worker in the same application domain inside IIS ? How might I approach this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Usually I do communication between ASP.NET and another process (a scheduled console application in most of my cases) through a database.

I.e. the ASP.NET application writes some jobs into a jobs table and the console application (which is being ran every 10 minutes or so through Windows Task Scheduler) picks up the jobs from the database table and processes them.

Comment: I understand, but I need very fast communication between the web application and the worker. The request comes in from the client -> I notify the worker -> the worker does his job -> calls back to the web application -> notifies the client.

Comment: @TomaCristian How about using [message queueing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue(v=VS.100).aspx)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you use a pattern? You're approach seems logical. Is it easy for your coworkers to maintain?

Comment: What are your opinions on using a background thread spawned from the Application_Start event of the web application ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an asynchronous IIS-hosted WCF or Web Service where the request is initiated from the client and the response is handled in the request completion callback.

Since IIS could instantiate a separate instance of your service class, this class could call the appropriate worker directly since the user won't be directly waiting on the response.

Comment: I am not worried about that. I need a worker that does work in the background and is able to push notifications to the clients through the SignalR connections that live in the web application instance.